# WordPress dynamic widget - how to remove markups and change class names?

Tags: wordpress, widget, wordpress-4.3

I added a new sidebar

```
function child_register_sidebar(){
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Social Media (Follow)',
        'id' => 'sidebar-follow',
        'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on all posts and pages.', 'theme-slug' ),
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ));

}
```

on my template,

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-follow' ) ) { ?>
    <div class="follow-container">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-follow' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

result:

```
<div class="follow-container">
      <div class="textwidget">
           <a href="[full link to your Twitter]">
              <img title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/01_twitter1.png" width="35" height="35" />
           </a>
      </div>
</div>
```

How can I remove `<div class="textwidget">` or change the class name to something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code for remove textwidget and apply own class in functions.php

```
    function register_my_widgets() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'test-widget',
        'id' => 'test-widget',
        'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on all posts and pages.', 'theme-slug' ),
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ));
    register_widget( 'My_Text_Widget' );
}

class My_Text_Widget extends WP_Widget_Text {
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract($args);
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );
        $text = apply_filters( 'widget_text', empty( $instance['text'] ) ? '' : $instance['text'], $instance );
        echo $before_widget;
        if ( !empty( $title ) ) { echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; } ?>
            <?php echo !empty( $instance['filter'] ) ? wpautop( $text ) : $text; ?>
        <?php
        echo $after_widget;
    }
}
```

Comment: it removes the entire widget content. result: `<div class="follow-container">
            </div>`

Answer (score 1):

Add `'class' => ''` to your arguments when registering sidebar if you want to remove the class or `'class' => 'myClass'` if you want use yours.

Registering the widget would look something like this:

```
function child_register_sidebar(){
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Social Media (Follow)',
        'id' => 'sidebar-follow',
        'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on all posts and pages.', 'theme-slug' ),
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
        'class' => 'myClass'
    ));

}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. The textwidget comes from Wordpress I think. You just registered a sidebar and put the standard WP Widget, not your own right ?

Comment: it is lame that you can't even change the class name.